# Tab character (\t) doesn't render in the lightning datatable in lwc

Tags: lightning-web-components, json, lightning-datatable

I am trying to render \t tab character along with \n in the lightning datable UI, but it doesn't seem to be working.
I am trying to use below JSON structure

`const data = [
        {
       name: "Title" ,
       Original: "ABC123",
       Change: "ABCD123\nReasons:\n\tReason1\n\tReason2",
       Operation: "changed",
        } 
       ]`

It outputs the change column in lightning datable as(without extra new line , that is fine):

ABCD123

Reasons:

Reason1

Reason2

**However , I want it to be something like below:-**

ABCD123

Reasons:

```
     Reason1 (tab characters added)

     Reason2 (tab characters added)
```

Ignore the grey background

Here is the link of the playground - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/kPSqiPxWk/53/edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think currently that is not possible with datatable because of the column of `type='text'` uses `lightning-formatted-text` component which only supports anchor tags.

I think you need the `lightning-formatted-rich-text`.

**But the good news is you can extend the functionality of datatable** by adding the custom column type. So you can use that method to add the rich text column in datatable using the `lightning-formatted-rich-text` component. In the rich text, you can use `&nbsp` four times or `&#9;` to represent the tab.

To know how to extend the datable with custom column type goto [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/documentation) and then goto **Creating Custom Data Types** section on that page.

### Or the easy way

This alternate solution is my personal choice you can go with this if you feel it ok. Just for adding the tabs, extending the datatable with custom column type will be lots of effort. Think this is just for formatting, in that case, I would have simply replaced the tabs with some formatting like `-----`, which will give me an output like.

```
ABCD123
Reasons:
----- Reason1
----- Reason2
```